# Getting error while adding angular.js file to plunker

Tags: angularjs, web-applications, plunker

I'm getting an error while adding a file (angular2.js) to my plunker. Can somebody please help me identifying and resolving the exact problem?

This is the screenshot of the error message [image: screenshot of the error message]

Answer (score 2):

Use this link and try.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

see this i create a `plunkr` (hello world program)

[plunkr here](https://plnkr.co/edit/UsLgAPwJEUXKQTXjnNmY?p=preview)